Translate expression bodied member to SQL so it can be used in LINQ where clauses?
Is it possible to write an extension to EF Core that tells it how to translate expression bodied members (or methods) to SQL so a getter/method can be used in where-clauses?
What I would like to achieve is the following:
public class Entity
{
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted => Deleted;
}

public class Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    public Task<List<Entity>> GetDeletedEntities()
    {
        return db.Set<Entity>().Where(e => e.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();
    }
}


EF can only do it if you change public bool IsDeleted to Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> =>  and a whole lot more. In short: no, there is no automatic Expression<Func<...>>-from-C#, at least OOB, but I suppose you could with a custom Roslyn code-generator...

@Dai it must be possible somehow. For instance, NodaTime does it with the function Instant.InZone as documented here.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv it's as "simple" as that and in order to improve our domain model API when writing LINQ queries. IsDeleted being a simplified example. Can you give some hints on how to do it?

@TommyJakobsen That's different - the Postgres+Noda library doesn't work by dynamically creating Expression<Func<> from arbitrary compiled C# - you'll notice that all of their samples work by using "normal" Expression<Func<...>> in Linq expressions, they only apply transformations to the expression-tree as the SQL is generated and is largely based on the  String name of the method/property being invoked.

public static readonly Expression<Entity, bool> IsDeleted = e => e.Deleted; and db.Set<Entity>().Where(Entity.IsDeleted).ToListAsync() is what I would use. You can't compose it though (it cannot appear inside another expression).

@Dai I'm not sure I follow. Looking at the NodaTime library Instant.InZone, they must translate this to SQL, which isn't much different from what I'm trying to achieve here, I believe?

@Charlieface Thanks - that is a workaround yes, but it's not what I'm hoping to achieve :-)

@TommyJakobsen Noda's Instant.InZone is translated to SQL right here - and it works by wallking the Linq Expression<> tree and matching Noda's symbols/identifiers to the things that have been manually and painstakingly translated as defined in NpgsqlNodaTimeMethodCallTranslator. So I restate: there is no easy way to somehow convert an already compiled C# class member into an Expression<> for use with Linq.
